# How do I reuse listview in tabs?

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, tabs

I would like to reuse a ListView in my flatter layout with two tabs. For example, I want to use it to display all books in the old testament and books in the new testament i.e., use the same ListView to display the two list on the different tabs. How do I accomplish this?
The following is the code I have come up with so far. I was thinking of using the tab controller to access the index of the current and use it to display the correct list. However, I am unable to do this and I can't seem to come up with the logic to do so. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation_drawer/tabs/old_testament.dart';
import 'package:navigation_drawer/tabs/new_testament.dart';
import 'package:navigation_drawer/model/book.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Testament",
    home: new HomeTab(),
  ));
}

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new TabState();
}

// SingleTickerProviderStateMixin is used for animation
class TabState extends State<HomeTab> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  // Create a tab controller
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize the Tab Controller
    controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the Tab Controller
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  TabBar getTabBar() {
    return new TabBar(
      tabs: <Tab>[
        new Tab(
          // set icon to the tab
          icon: new Icon(Icons.brightness_2),
          text: "Old Testament",
        ),
        new Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.brightness_6),
          text: "New Testament",
        ),
      ],
      // setup the controller
      controller: controller,
    );
  }

  TabBarView getTabBarView(var tabs) {
    return new TabBarView(
      // Add tabs as widgets
      children: tabs,
      // set the controller
      controller: controller,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      // Appbar
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        // Title
        title: new Text("Testament"),
        // Set the background color of the App Bar
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        // Set the bottom property of the Appbar to include a Tab Bar
        bottom: getTabBar()
      ),
      // Set the TabBar view as the body of the Scaffold
      body: getTabBarView(<Widget>[new OldTestament(), new NewTestament()])
    );
  }    
}

class ListTab extends StatefulWidget {
  ListTab({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ListTabState();
}

class ListTabState extends State<ListTab> {
  List books;

  @override
  void initState() {
    books = getOldTestamentBooks(); 
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // create a list tile for books
    ListTile makeListTile(Book book) => ListTile(
      contentPadding:
      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
      leading: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          border: new Border(
            right: new BorderSide(
              width: 1.0,
              color: Colors.blue
            )
          )
        ),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.book,
          color: Colors.grey
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(
        book.title,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
      ),

      subtitle: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                  book.testament,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
              )
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      trailing: Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 30.0
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    );

    // create a card view for the list tile
    Card makeCard(Book book) => Card(
      elevation: 8.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: makeListTile(book),
      ),
    );

    final makeBody = Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: books.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return makeCard(books[index]);
        },
      ),
    );


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: makeBody,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to reuse the same Listview for displaying a list of books (old testament in one tab and new testament in the other one).
What I suggest you to do is to create a widget that contains only the Listview.builder, and the ListTile model, that would take the list of books as an argument for the constructor.

After separating the ListView widget from the ListTab, the new widget class would look like this:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation_drawer/model/book.dart';

class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Book> _books;

  BookList(this._books);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _books.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 8.0,
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                leading: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      border: new Border(right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.blue))),
                  child: Icon(Icons.book, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  _books[index].title,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                          child:
                              Text(_books[index].testament, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.black, size: 30.0),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And your ListTab widget would look like this:

```js
class ListTab extends StatefulWidget {
  ListTab({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ListTabState();
}

class ListTabState extends State<ListTab> {
  List books;

  @override
  void initState() {
    books = getOldTestamentBooks(); 
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: BookList(books),
    );
  }
}
```

In this way, you can reuse the BookList widget in whichever tab you want.

Comment: Yes you understood me correctly and thank you. If I may ask, do the two widgets go on one file?

Comment: I would keep them in different files. Usually I do 1 file per widget.